# don't save post with 6000 words or more per post of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, save

I want to insert a post with 6000 words or more on my site (powered by wordpress cms) but I get an error.
My site is on a dedicated server with 16 GB of RAM.
please help.

I put the content less than 4000 words, the post will be saved, but not more than that.
In addition, my words are not Latin, but Persian.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.